# Python Error SQLACHEMY

Tags: sql, python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Está dando um erro quando tento fazer a conexão ao banco de dados SQL SERVER com SQLALCHEMY

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, engine
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://User:password@server:1433/Bases_testes?drive=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11')
query = "SELECT * FROM dv_rating"
result = pd.read_sql(query,engine)

print(result)
```

e Mostra esse error

sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

Mas não consigo achar o erro, já intalei o PYODBC e o sql native client e mesmo assim não consigo a conexão

Answer (score 2):

Talvez seja melhor você utilizar o **driver ODBC do SQL Server** no lugar do **sql native client**.

Para saber se você tem o driver instalado execute:

```
print([x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith('ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server')])
```

Caso seja retornada uma lista vazia instale o driver:

- [Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-2017).
- [Linux/macOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Para conexão com o **MS SQL Server** eu utilizo:

```
import pyodbc    
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# String de conexão Windows Server.
parametros = (
    # Driver que será utilizado na conexão
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    # IP ou nome do servidor\Versão do SQL.
    'SERVER=192.168.100.178\SQLEXPRESS;'
    # Porta
    'PORT=1433;'
    # Banco que será utilizado.
    'DATABASE=PythonMSSQL;'
    # Nome de usuário.
    'UID=python;'
    # Senha.
    'PWD=123456')

# Convertendo a string para um padrão de URI HTML.
url_db = quote_plus(parametros)

# Conexão.
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % url_db)
```

Vale lembrar que configurações adicionais no servidor ou mesmo no SQL Server podem ser necessárias (tipo de login, firewall, permitir conexões TCP, porta, etc).